# Adobe Sign - How can I add the signer name with text tags?

Tags: adobe-sign

I want to put the name of the signer in the transient document I sent. I tried with:

> {{fn_es_:signer1:firstname}}

> {{ln_es_:signer1:lastname}}

> {{Name_es_:signer1:fullname}}

> {{N_es_:signer1:fullname}}

but this only captures the strings that the signer put in the signature field after they signed.

I want to do some similar to this:

> {{Em_es_:signer1:email}}

that this automatically has the email and the signer doesn't need to do anything else.

this is the JSON I'm sending:

```json
{
    "fileInfos": [
        {
            "transientDocumentId": transientDocumentId
        }
    ],
    "name": "Test",
    "participantSetsInfo": [
        {
            "order": 1,
            "role": "SIGNER",
            "name": "Signer1",
            "id": "signer1",
            "memberInfos": [
                {
                    "email": emailSigner1,
                    "id": "signer1",
                    "name": "Signer1",
                    "nameInfo": {
                        "firstName": "Signer",
                        "lastName": "One"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "order": 2,
            "role": "SIGNER",
            "name": "Signer2",
            "id": "signer2",
            "memberInfos": [
                {
                    "email": emailSigner2,
                    "id": "signer2",
                    "name": "Signer2",
                    "nameInfo": {
                        "firstName": "Signer",
                        "lastName": "Two"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "signatureType": "ESIGN",
    "state": "IN_PROCESS"
}
```